# Migrations don't run automatically when I paste dll files in bin of publish folder, ASP.NET MVC / Entity Framework, new tables/columns not generate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web, migration

[Automatic migrations are set to true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeHWA.png)

After this I paste my dll files in the publish folder but I get this error:

> Context has changed since the last migrations, try running migrations on model.

Comment: have you tried, enter update-database -verbose under your package manager console to update the db first then try to run again